# Generating Typescript Definition from partial classes using Web Essentials

Tags: c#, entity-framework, typescript, web-essentials

I'm trying to get my typescript definition files generated for my database first entity framework classes using web essentials 2015 with VS 2015.

I followed the example [here](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html) to generate my .net classes the new way, and i have POCOs for all the tables. e.g.

```
//module User.cs
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Usually, i will extend these will some partial classes so i can add some functionality outside of the database, i wouldn't modify my generated code in case i need to regenerate it later.

```
//module SiteModels.cs
public partial class User
{
    public double DaysOld { get { return (DateTime.Now - DateOfBirth).TotalDays ;  } }
}
```

But web essentials only looks at the code in the file that i am generating a typescript intellisense file for, so in my typescript definition i only get:

```
//generated module SiteModels.cs.d.ts
interface User {
        daysOld: number;
    }
```

So the crux of the problem is: when i have 2 partial class in 2 different files, and i am using web essentials to convert one to a typescript definition file, it's not including all of the properties from both partial classes.

Suggestions for alternate routes are acceptable, but they need to work with ASP NET Core.

Comment: can you please throw few more details? I'm not getting the last part.

Comment: I just realised i had the wrong name on the generated interface, does it make sense now? it's not bringing in the properties from the EF generated partial class..